# Gvim | Vim consola Windows

Tags: windows, terminal, vim

Tengo una duda con Gvim y Nvim en windows.

Este es mi path de neovim

```
AppData/Local/nvim/init.vim
```

Quisiera saber el de Gvim.

Lo instale, le instale plugins y todo pero la consola hace que las lineas se muestren duplicadas a menos que pases el cursor por arriba de todas las lineas por eso lei que se podia instalar Gvim el editor de texto de vim por ahora no tuve problemas pero no se como añadir mi configuración o donde esta ese archivo para agregarle plugins o mis propios Set.

Agradecería si me pueden ayudar a configurarlo. O si es mejor direcatamente ejecutar una maquina virtual con linux o si alguien sabe de algun emulador de consola. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El archivo de configuración para Gvim es **_vimrc** y se encuentra en el directorio donde se ha instalado Gvim. Sin embargo dependiendo de la versión de Gvim puede que el archivo no exista. En mi caso por ejemplo sobre Windows no lo tengo pero la instalación de Gvim 73 ha generado un ejemplo de este archivo llamado vimrc_example.vim

[image: Directorio de instalación de Gvim]

El archivo de ejemplo también te dice donde y como debe llamarse el archivo de configuración.

[image: Archivo de configuración]

Finalmente te comento que Gvim y NeoVim no son enteramente compatibles, existirán plugins que solo funcionen con NeoVim y muy posiblemente habrá plugins que no

Saludos